# possible to make a request without redirecting the page and without using javascript?

Tags: html, http

I just want to send a post request to an api. So far I have:

```
<form method="POST" action="/api/updoot/ID:{{ post.ID }}">
    <input type="submit" value="updoot"/>
</form>
```

When I click submit it redirects. I know how to prevent the redirection with javascript but I was wondering if it's possible to send the request without using javascript and without redirecting the user?

Comment: No you can't, If you want to alter its default behavior JavaScript is always involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to make an HTTP request, without page re-direction, and without any JavaScript.

The trick is: make an invisible `iframe`, and use it as the target of `form`. In this way, when `form` is submitted, the HTTP request is sent, and the response will be processed in `iframe`. As the `iframe` is invisible, nothing would change in page.

Here is an example:

```css
#subframe {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://requestb.in/xkaff3xk" target="sub">
  <input type="text" name="test">
  <input type="submit" value="updoot"/>
</form>
<iframe id="subframe" name="sub">

</iframe>
```